# Phonegap APIs working on Windows Phone only

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, phonegap-build

I have created a simple application using Phonegap and Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone 7. After that I used phonegap build to get the compiled files for Android (.apk) and Windows Phone (.xap). Its working fine in Windows Phone 7 but not on two of the Android phones I am available with.

I have used the examples given in Phonegap website. I have tried to access following through api:

1. Accelerometer
2. Geolocation
3. Device Properties
4. Camera

In starting I thought it's version problem but even Accelerometer isn't working which is not bound to any version of android mobile, I am sure there is something wrong.

Would someone show an HTML file containing any of the examples, so that I can use Phonegap build and get assured that something is wrong at my end.

Comment: I've used phonegap for it's geolocation api and wasn't able to make it  work properly on Android until I rebooted the device. It is interesting to note that native applications using geolocation were working fine.

Comment: @inf1ux thanks for the comment let me try with a reboot. Could it be the problem with other ones I mentioned ?

Comment: Sorry, I just shared my experience on the topic - haven't tried the others. Hope it helps.